# How do I move my Knockout code out of my View and still be able to map the ViewModels?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I'm currently trying to map my MVC view model into the knockout viewmodel. I'm using the mapping extension for knockout to automatically do this.

I can work it working when the javascript is in view because I can just directly reference the viewmodel with razor code like so...

> ```
> var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
> indexViewModel.serverViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
> ```

However, when the javascript is in a seperate file, I'm unsure what to do.

I decided to put the MVC view model into a hidden variable (not sure if i'm meant to do this).

```
@Html.Hidden("Model", @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)))
```

and then reference it in my JS like so

```
var model = $('#Model').val();   
indexViewModel.serverViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
```

The problem now is that it doesn't seem to be mapping.

I've looked at the contents of model in both the JS-in-View and the seperate JS file version and they both output

```
{"companies":[{"Key":1,"Value":"BHP       "}]}
```

which is the JSON that I'm after.

It's just that for some reason in the seperate JS file, ko.mapping.fromJS(model) returns a string where as the JS-in-View version returns it as a hierachy of observables().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first samaple:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
indexViewModel.serverViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
```

the `model` variable holds a JS object which can be mapped with `ko.mapping.fromJS(model)`.

However in your second example:

```
var model = $('#Model').val();
```

the `model` now contains a JSON string which need to mapped differenlty with `ko.mapping.fromJSON` method:

So the following should work:

```
var model = $('#Model').val();   
indexViewModel.serverViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(model);
```

See also the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), Working with JSON strings section.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
var model = $('#Model').val();
```

is returning a `string` whereas `ko.mapping.fromJS` is expecting a JavaScript object (`"fromJS"`).

Try:

```
var model = JSON.parse($('#Model').val());
```